# After copying data and system directories of datanode, why did the data still cannot be queried in the new server of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently have two stand-alone instances of Apache IoTDB server (A and B). Both of which are run by docker, while server A is newly started. After I copy server B's `data/datanode/data` and `data/datanode/system` directory to the corresponding directory of server A, and started server A, the data still cannot be queried out in server A. I wonder which step I did wrong or what else should I do to be able to query data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `load` command in Apache IoTDB to successfully import the data from server A to server B. All your other steps are correct, so try to execute `load data` statement and try query again.